# how can show 100 character and hide more for expander?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, expander, ellipsis

I have a dynamic site with MySQL database and I want to create "*see more*" button just like on Facebook, and I should probably use jQuery expander, but I have a big problem. I don't know how can I hide more characters...

Bellow is my code:

```
if ( $message = mb_strlen(htmlspecialchars($this->post_message) ) > 200 ); {
    $message = str_cut(htmlspecialchars($this->post_message),100);
    echo $message.'<span style="float:left;clear:both"> <a href="" target="_blank" title="more" style="font-size:9px;" >more</a></span>';
}
```

who can handle complete code for this ?
This code just *cuts* more characters, but I want to hide them and show in expander!

Sorry for my bad language, I don't speak English well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax.

```
if ( $message   =  mb_strlen(htmlspecialchars($this->post_message) ) > 200 ); {
```

Should be

```
if ( $message   =  mb_strlen(htmlspecialchars($this->post_message) ) > 200 ) {
```

There should be no `;` after your if statement

`str_cut` is not a PHP function. What you are looking for is [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

In your case, you would use it like this:

```
$message = substr(htmlspecialchars($this->post_message),0,100);
```

Comment: i know about that dear . but my problem is here str_cut ! i don't know what a code replace with str_cut for work !

Comment: not work with $message = substr(htmlspecialchars($this->post_message),0,100);